# A graphic novel about a boy disappearing for star-gazing too much

Tags: story-identification

Sorry, it only came to me suddenly that it **was** a graphic novel, not SF but Fantasy.

I read it more than 40 years ago. I read it in French, but it might have been a translation, from English or any other language.

I remember very little, but the story is never very long in a graphic novel. There was this boy who was not interested in anything except star-gazing. All attempts by his parents, or friends, to get him interested in anything else failed.  There might even have been a girl who had for him unrequited, not really love, but interest. At the end he spends a whole night in front of an open window looking at stars....  and in the morning he isn't there anymore.